# regular expression question mark

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to construct a regular expression query which excludes `"/php?/"` from the results, but I'm not sure how to get question mark to be recognized as part of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the escape character `\`

i.e. `/php\?/`

If you are constructing it as a string, you will have to escape the escape character for the string.

i.e. `"/php\\?/"`